# Error read addres with function ReadProcessMemory c#

Tags: c#, readprocessmemory

I have an error with reading the memory address of the game, where:
my code is this

```html
public partial class MainWindow: Window
    {
        [DllImport ("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess (int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport ("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory (int hProcess, int lpBaseAddress, byte [] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);
        const int PROCESS_WM_READ = 0x0010;

        public MainWindow ()
        {
            arguments dir = new arguments ();
            Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName (dir.proccessname) [0];
            IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess (PROCESS_WM_READ, false, process.Id);
            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte [] buffer = new byte [4]; 
            ReadProcessMemory ((int) processHandle, dir.heal_Act, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);
        }
```

however, nothing reading appears:
in cheat engine read me the values

[Read address with Cheat Engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/addfv.png)
Where in the image appears the reading of the memory address and finally the value contained with 4 bytes in size
[Read address with Cheat Engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDcXT.png)
In addition, I do not know how the summation of the address is as shown in box 2 to obtain the contained value.
they could help me to propose the reading with the indicated address, since zero appears.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your process as administrator and you should compile this for the same architecture as the target process.  If you're targetting x86, compile as x86.

Keep in mind your ReadProcessMemory define only takes 4 byte addresses as arguments, you will want to use IntPtr for the addresses so when you someday switch to x64 the args will be large enough for 64 bit pointers.

If these things don't solve your problem then you're offsets or addresses are wrong.  In which case the best thing to do is to use the Visual Studio Debugger and compare what you see against what you see in Cheat Engine.

Also in your PROCESS_WM_READ you have a 'W' instead of a 'V'.